# Emacs: How can I use a save list to restore buffers from crash?

Tags: emacs, crash

If you enable the desktop feature, you can return to your previously open set of files when you exit and reenter Emacs. This doesn't seem to be a crash recovery feature however.

If Emacs crashes, there is a save list called "saves-PID-machine" that has a list of the files that had buffers. The list has the full path to both the file itself and the corresponding `~` backup file.

How do I use this save list to get back to the set of visited files in buffers that I had before the crash? None of the files had edits pending so recover-session and recover-file don't do anything.

Comment: See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeskTop for some approaches to auto-saving the desktop periodically. This doesn't answer the question, but it's a pretty decent workaround.

Answer (score 5):

You can download and install https://github.com/tripleee/recover-buffers which visits all the files in the auto-save file, and offers to recover any for which unsaved auto-save data exists.

```
    ;;; recover-buffers.el --- revisit all buffers from an auto-save file
    ;;
    ;;; Commentary:
    ;;
    ;; Works like `recover-session', but attempts to really recover all state
    ;; back to the way it was when Emacs quit or crashed.  Concretely, it
    ;; revisits all buffers which were open, however skipping any which match
    ;; an ignore list.
```

There is an open Emacs bug about this, too; http://debbugs.gnu.org/889

I am the author of this code, and would appreciate any feedback (though not via this public forum).

Answer (score 0):

Tried M-x recover-session ?

> (recover-session)
>   Recover auto save files from a previous Emacs session.
>   This command first displays a Dired buffer showing you the
>   previous sessions that you could recover from.
>   To choose one, move point to the proper line and then type C-c C-c.
>   Then you'll be asked about a number of files to recover.

Comment: Julien, you are describing the method that doesn't work. If all the files have been saved, and then the editor crashes (typically not an emacs crash), then recover-session just says there's nothing to recover, even though the recovery file has a long list of files. It seems that the recover-session feature uses additional information to find out if the file listed had unsaved changes. It would recover the edits to such a file. Otherwise the feature doesn't visit the file.